# xpages extension Library dialog read only

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Can the xpages extension library dialog box (xe:dialog) be open so that it's fields are read only ?

Lotus Domino 8.5.3 version update 1 extlib

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you make a panel control read only, the controls within the panel control are read only too. So, add your fields inside a panel control and make it read only:

```
<xp:panel readonly="true">

  Add your fields here

</xp:panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

The content of the dialog is defined by the structures declared within it, so you'd just make your elements within the content area computed text, or readonly fields, however you want to do it. If your question is can it be opened read-only sometimes, save a variable to the scope and use that to determine whether or not to render controls as editable.